# How to map EditModel to Command Messages?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mapping, automapper

Jimmy Bogard at Los Techies [says that he maps his EditModel to Command Messages](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/09/17/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper.aspx) instead of mapping EditModel to DomainModel. Can anyone explain this further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess it'd be a version of the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) that performs the necessary manipulations on the relevant domain objects based on the supplied message. e.g. Something like

```
public PromoteEmployeeCommand : ICommand {
     private readonly PromotionMessage _message;
     private readonly IEmployeeRepository _repository;

     public PromoteEmployeeCommand(PromotionMessage message,
                                   IEmployeeRepository repository) {
          _message = message;
          _repository = repository;
     }

     public void Execute() {
          /* Get the employee, give them a rise etc... */
     }
}
```

The mapping from the edit model would resolve to a number of command messages that could be invoked as required (e.g. Give employee a rise, notify their manager, add a note for payroll etc).

The advantage of this approach is that it can isolate your domain model from any presentational concerns exposed by the Edit model.