# How to use ViewModel in ASPNET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn ASPNET MVC. I've built a `DbModel` starting from DB structure so, under Models, I have the `.edmx` file that can be used to access data.

I've read that it could be good to have ViewModels classes to act between the View and the Model (useful also for single fields formatting) but I don't' understand if this is right and in which way it's better to build them. If they reproduce classes in my model I believe it is a little bit redundant, isn't it? If this is the right way, is there a way to generate automatically ViewModel classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ViewModel in MVC is a model of your view. It is a property bag containing, usually of primitive types. It may seem redundant, but you are protecting yourself from future problems by decoupling your code.

As an example, given a Person object in your domain model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}     // John
    public string LastName {get; set;}      // Doe
    public DateTime Birthdate {get; set;}   // 01/01/1965
}
```

In your view, you may want to represent this in a view as a full name, age and birthday.  Your ViewModel would be similar to:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FullName {get; set;}     // John Doe
    public int Age {get; set;}             // 46
    public int Birthday {get; set;}        // January 1
}
```

Somewhere in your pipeline, you need to convert from domain model to the viewmodel. I have used either projection queries from the persistence layer or object-to-object mapping frameworks, such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

By structuring your data this way, you can keep logic and formatting rules out of your view markup.  By using a framework, such as AutoMapper, you can also standardize string formatting of dates and times, and do convention-based mappings.

Also, I generally advise having one ViewModel per View. If you need to share View/ViewModel structures or apply conditional view information, those should be separated into partial views.

Comment: Would you be kind enough as to provide a suggestion on how to handle a form post scenario?.. Im having a hard time converting from the viewmodel to the Business model.. Automapper, I have read, is not really meant to handle this scenario and the only logical way of handling this seems to be either provide a constructor in my business model that receives a viewmodel instance to construct the model or wrting left to write code in my controller (which also seems kind of odd).. what do you suggest?

Comment: In your controller, provide an `ActionResult` attributed with `[HttpPost]` that takes a parameter object with properties that match your form elements. The MVC model binder will fill those properties with your form element values.  Take that object and pass it to your service. (I've called these form view models, or form model for short. But it is just a DTO with only the pieces you need to update the domain model)

Comment: Ok, so in the service I would then set the correct properties from the viewmodel to the business model, right? something kind of like this.

Comment: sorry.. didnt make it in time to edit and add this pic... something kind of like this?? http://imgur.com/m9olR    I dont mind this approach it just seems somewhat odd that to map from business to DTO I use automapper and from DTO to Business I have to write all this code.... I would appreciate your input on this... :)

Comment: If you are not doing any transformation, there is no need to have the dto in the middle (unless you will update the implementation later). If you need a transformation, you can use automapper to do that transformation as well, including updating an existing entity. The abstraction still makes sense.

Comment: You may want to look at these: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901196/how-to-map-editmodel-to-command-messages

Comment: @NachoF let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1392/discussion-between-richard-cirerol-and-nachof)

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting out I would avoid trying to incorporate every best practice you can find into your early applications.  It becomes very easy to try and do everything everyone says is the best practice and you lose track of just learning the fundamentals.

View Models are obviously a great way of seperating the presentation layer and the domain layer, but they serve other purposes.  If you are just starting out and your applications are not terribly complicated, I would recommend keeping it simple and use your domain classes as your view model where your views are simple.  This will allow you to focus more on the application.

Also, by doing this you will come across views where the simple domain model will not cut it and you will find yourself needing a ViewModel.  Which will allow you to incorporate the more specific information you need for your view page (such as multiple domain objects).

By practicing without using View Models for everything, you can gain an appreciation for their benefits and decide what works best for you and your code.

Answer (score 1):

A "view model" (model for a view rather than domain model) helps you separate the domain model from what is bound to the page. Is it always necessary? No, but it is useful if you have some common data shapes used on multiple views where the view will also have some additional data. Another good use is removing certain data from certain types of views (your customer should not know your margin, but your management should?). IT is not mandatory.